# Difference in a array of probability density plots for the electron in its lowest-energy states of Hydrogen atom

Tags: electrons, electronic-configuration, periodic-table

[image: An array of Plot of probability density for Hydrogen atom electron]

[Dynamic Periodic Table](https://www.ptable.com)

If you visit Dynamic Peridic Table, You will notice that for n=4 l=3,2 m=0,0, and n=2,l=1, m=0 there is a difference in  the probability density plots for electron in its stationary energy state of Hydrogen atom  and image of arrays of probability density plots attached herewith titled'Hydrogen Wave Function'.

Why do we found such discrepancies? or are these plots  same?

If any member knows the answer to this question, may reply.

Comment: What difference? In not inclined to check random site just you say there's some "difference". One could colour such pics in whatever way for any particular electron density.